# Send path from controller to a service which will return a promise back to controller

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have a service which get data from a file(path is given by the controller) and return a promise - then another service that create a object with properties using the returned data from the last service.

My problems are:

1. The **getDataService** runs before controller so it has no path from which to fetch data => nothing in return(an error)

> Provider 'GetDataService' must return a value from $get factory method.

2. I need to keep this structure because I'll have more controllers with different paths to give
3. I'm also opened to other solutions but I need to make sure that datas are loaded before the template get populated. I've tried to call SetProperties service first with getData service into it - but still getData.js is executed first

**getdata Service**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('GetDataService',['$http', function($http) {
    var getData = function(path){
        return  $http.get(path).then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

**setProperties service**

```
angular.module('myApp').service('PageProperties',['$http', function($http) {

    this.setProps = function(page, data) {      

            some code here

        var properties = {
                isCenterActive : isActive_val,
                //header elements
                titleClass : page, 
                title : data.titles[page],
                //footer elements
                leftLink : leftLink_val,
                leftFooterClass: leftLink_val,
                leftTitle: data.titles[leftLink_val],
                centerLink : centerLink_val,
                centerFooterClass: data.titles[centerLink_val],
                centerTitle : centerTitle_val,
                rightLink : rightLink_val,
                rightFooterClass: rightLink_val ,
                rightTitle : data.titles[rightLink_val],            
            }

        return properties;
    }
}]);
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('meniuController', ['$http', '$stateParams', '$scope', 'GetDataService', 'PageProperties', 
            function($http, $stateParams, $scope, GetDataService, PageProperties){      
    var page = "meniu";
    $scope.language = $stateParams.lang;
    var path = '_global/views/services/json/' + $stateParams.lang + '_data.json';

    /*PageProperties.setProps(page, path).then(function(data){
        //some code here
    });*/
    GetDataService.getData(path).then(function(data){
        $scope.props = PageProperties.setProps(page, data);
    }).catch(function(){
        $scope.error = 'Unable to get data';
    });
}])
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The error says your `GetDataService` provider (defined as factory) doesn't return anything

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('GetDataService',['$http', function($http) {
    var getData = function(path){
        return  $http.get(path).then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    };

    // you need to actually return something

    return { getData: getData };
}]);
```

Then you can make your `PageProperties` use `GetDataService`

```
angular
   .module('myApp')
   .service('PageProperties',['GetDataService', function(GetDataService) { 
      this.getProperties = function(path) {
         return GetDataService.getData(path).then(/*transform here*/)
      }
```

Comment: Ok, now I have one more:  I'm using ui-router and on a template that is populated by this controller I have three `ui-sref' which load before service is getting data. How can I pass this?